# Improve comparing between two collections - LINQ? C#

Tags: c#, list, linq

**Edit:**
**_existingRatings and _targetRatings are both collections from a database, where Rating and RatingType are both key/values.**

I've got two RatingDto collections that I need to compare each other against: _existingRates and _targetRates. I'll be simply doing a comparison on the RatingTypeId, then need to check if the same one in the _targetRates has an empty Rating string.

As it's Monday morning, my brain is still asleep and I'm sure there's a better and simpler way to do this with LINQ. This is what I'm currently doing:

```
class RatingDto
{
        public int RatingTypeId { get; set; }
        public string RatingType { get; set; }
        public string Rating { get; set; }
}

foreach (var existing in _existingRatings)
{
    foreach(var target in _targetRatings)
    {
        if(existing.RatingTypeId == target.RatingTypeId)
        {
            if(target.Rating == string.Empty)
            {
                _targetHasMissingRatings = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This should be okay as the maximum amount is around 7 in each collection, but I'm sure there's a better and cleaner way with LINQ.

Comment: Do you care if `_targetRates` that do not have a matching object in the `_existingRates` have an empty `Rating`?

Comment: @AsheraH Nope, just directly checking existingRatings to targetRatings, not the other way round. I've gone with CorrM's answer below though, seems to work well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's should what you are looking for :
(i love to use `string.IsNullOrEmpty` rather than cmp string.Empty)

```
_targetHasMissingRatings = _existingRatings.Any(er => string.IsNullOrEmpty(_targetRatings.FirstOrDefault(tr => er.RatingTypeId == tr.RatingTypeId)?.Rating));
```

Comment: We are taking `_targetRattings.FirstOrDefault` everytime. will it cause any issue for the requirement of OP. There is no `break` implemented in OP's code.

Comment: in his Question he say `This should be okay as the maximum amount is around 7 in each collection`, so it's okay.

Comment: I believe this should be fine. @Amit the break should've actually been there, as I'm only setting a flag, so that's my mistake. Also, the RatingTypeId's are unique in both. Will test it now!

Answer (score 1):

Use IComparable so you can use OrderBy on the entire class or simply compare two instances of the class.

```
List<RatingDto> ordered = _existingRatings.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
```

See code below :

```
    class RatingDto : IComparable<RatingDto>
    {
        public int RatingTypeId { get; set; }
        public string RatingType { get; set; }
        public string Rating { get; set; }

        public int CompareTo(RatingDto  other)
        {
            if (this.RatingTypeId != other.RatingTypeId)
            {
                return this.RatingTypeId.CompareTo(other.RatingTypeId);
            }
            else
            {
                return this.RatingType.CompareTo(other.RatingType);
            }
        }
    }
```

---

Code would look like this :

```
            List<RatingDto> _existingRatings = new List<RatingDto>(); 
            List<RatingDto> _targetRatings = new List<RatingDto>();
            Boolean _targetHasMissingRatings = false;

            foreach (var existing in _existingRatings)
            {
                foreach (var target in _targetRatings)
                {
                    if (existing == target)
                    {
                         _targetHasMissingRatings = true;
                         break;
                    }
                }
                if (_targetHasMissingRatings == true) break;
            }
```